# docker executable behaviour differences on diff DOCKERHOSTS, seek advise

Tags: docker, host

I need some help with docker executable behaving in a different way on two diff hosts.

When I run a docker image on one of the DOCKER_HOST, named ansi-01, **all is well**

[image: a WORKING DOCKER HOSTt]

The same exact thing when I run from this other DOCKER_HOST named jnks-01

[image: a NON-WORKING DOCKER HOSTt]

As can be seen in the pictures, the docker versions are the same for both the WORKING_DOCKER_HOST and NON-WORKING_DOCKER_HOST.

`So has anyone seen this odd behavior?`

Checked the image id on the *working* DOCKER_HOST and the *non-working* DOCKER_HOST.

Working one:
`dtr.......com/paas/sles11sp4-updated                latest                                                    feac1ea1fa1d`

Non-working one:
`dtr.......com/paas/sles11sp4-updated                latest                    feac1ea1fa1d`

Working: uname -a
`Linux ansi-01 4.4.74-92.38-default #1 SMP Tue Sep 12 19:43:46 UTC 2017 (545c055) x86_64 x86_64 x86_64 GNU/Linux`

Non-working one
`Linux jnks-01 4.4.74-92.38-default #1 SMP Tue Sep 12 19:43:46 UTC 2017 (545c055) x86_64 x86_64 x86_64 GNU/Linux`

Why this odd discrepancy in the behaviour of docker executable in diff DOCKER_HOSTS ?

Expected result is docker executable behaves the same across all DOCKER_HOSTS for the same docker executables.

Comment: compare the digest of the images from both hosts to see if they are exactly the same, because once you use the tag `latest` is no guarantee they are the same: `docker images --digests | grep -i image-name -`. Also check the alias of the shell in both images: `alias | grep -i ls -` and `which ls`. Add the output to your question.

Comment: Could you share the dockerfile that created the image? It is possible that you have a persistent volume defined for /usr/local/bin (for example) and that on one machine somebody has installed ls into it, and on the other machine, not.

Comment: Thank you @Abulafia for your time.

Comment: @Exadra37  please see my answers  with pictures I have provided.

Comment: @Abulafia, Please see my response as answers

Answer (score 0):

Thank you @Abulafia for your time and attention.

Regarding question about Docker file from @Abulafia

```
    #!/bin/bash

# Install RPM package .. sles11sp4-docker-image from repo
# Install package if it is not there..
sudo zypper --non-interactive install sles11sp4-docker-image

PKGNAME=`rpm -qa | grep sles11sp4-docker-image`

TARFILE=`rpm -ql ${PKGNAME} | grep tar.xz`

TARFILEBASENAME=`basename "$TARFILE" .tar.xz`

FILE="Dockerfile"

IMAGENAME_FROM_RPM="sles11sp4-orig"

TAG_VERSION_FROM_RPM=`echo ${PKGNAME} | cut -d "-" -f 4`

IMAGENAME="sles11sp4-updated"

NAMESPACEDEST="pid-paas"

CURR_DIR=`pwd`

DATE=`date -u +%Y%m%d%H%M%S`

BUILD_DIR=`mktemp -d ~/sles11sp4-updated-${DATE}-XXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXX`

cd $BUILD_DIR

cp -p /usr/share/suse-docker-images/${TARFILEBASENAME}.tar.xz .

xz -d ${TARFILEBASENAME}.tar.xz

docker import - ${IMAGENAME_FROM_RPM}:${TAG_VERSION_FROM_RPM} < ${TARFILEBASENAME}.tar

rm -vf ${TARFILEBASENAME}.tar

cd ..

rmdir -v $BUILD_DIR



The docker file build out occurs here
<pre>
/bin/cat <<EOM > $FILE
FROM ${IMAGENAME_FROM_RPM}:${TAG_VERSION_FROM_RPM}
MAINTAINER $MAINTAINER

RUN \\
    set -ex \\
    && rpm -e container-suseconnect \\
    && zypper addrepo -G \\
        $SLES11SP4_POOL_REPO_URL \\
        $SLES11SP4_POOL_REPO_ALIAS \\
    && zypper addrepo -G \\
        $SLES11SP4_UPDATES_REPO_URL \\
        $SLES11SP4_UPDATES_REPO_ALIAS \\
    && zypper addrepo -G \\
        $SLES11SP4_UPDATES_QUARTER_REPO_URL \\
        $SLES11SP4_UPDATES_QUARTER_REPO_ALIAS \\
    && ${SLES_PROXY_CACHE} zypper --non-interactive update \\
    # timezone for being able to set EST time inside container
    && ${SLES_PROXY_CACHE} zypper --non-interactive install timezone \\
    # bind-utils for dig
    && ${SLES_PROXY_CACHE} zypper --non-interactive install bind-utils \\
    # netcat-openbsd
    && ${SLES_PROXY_CACHE} zypper --non-interactive install netcat-openbsd \\
    # tcpdump
    && ${SLES_PROXY_CACHE} zypper --non-interactive install tcpdump \\
    # telnet
    && ${SLES_PROXY_CACHE} zypper --non-interactive install telnet \\
    # curl, wget and tar
    && ${SLES_PROXY_CACHE} zypper --non-interactive install curl wget tar \\
    && zypper clean \\
    && zypper removerepo $SLES11SP4_POOL_REPO_ALIAS \\
                        $SLES11SP4_UPDATES_REPO_ALIAS \\
                        $SLES11SP4_UPDATES_QUARTER_REPO_ALIAS

ENV TZ America/New_York

EOM

#DATE=`date -u +%Y%m%d%H%M%S`
TAG_VERSION=$DATE

docker build --no-cache=true -t ${IMAGENAME}:${TAG_VERSION} . && rm -f Dockerfile
docker tag ${IMAGENAME}:${TAG_VERSION} ${IMAGENAME}:latest
```